# unixodbc driver manager cannot open specified library on install

Tags: odbc, archlinux, unixodbc, openedge, progress-db

I'm using ArchLinux and I am trying to install OpenEdge progress drivers so I can access it via PHP.  I've installed the unixodbc package and the drivers, but when I test the connection via isql or PHP, I get the same error...

```
# isql -3 SUBS2A
[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1023.so' : file not found
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

The messed up thing is that "/usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1023.so" presently exists, I even symlinked it from "/usr/dlc".

The following are my .ini files...

odbc.ini

```
[SUBS2A]
Description = ODBC Driver for Progress
Driver = /usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1023.so
FileUsage = 1
```

odbcinst.ini (I removed some of the credentials as it is irrelevant)

```
[ODBC-test]
Description = SUBS2A
Driver = SUBS2A
Server = 192.168.1.2
Port = 4000
APILevel=1
ConnectFunctions=YYN
CPTimeout=60
DriverODBCVer=03.60
FileUsage=0
SQLLevel=0
UsageCount=1
ArraySize=50
DefaultLongDataBuffLen=2048
DefaultIsolationLevel= READ COMMITTED
StaticCursorLongColBuffLen=4096
```

*EDIT* Adding more info...

They appear to both be 32-bit, except I have no idea what I'm doing regarding that.

```
[root@Crux etc]# file /usr/bin/isql
/usr/bin/isql: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.27, BuildID[sha1]=0xd1bc16c119                          bb5cad6fea9e2a9abc1d06794a2775, stripped
[root@Crux etc]# file /usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1023.so
/usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1023.so: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

It does appear that it's missing some dependencies...

```
[root@Crux lib]# ldd pgoe1023.so
        linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb77c2000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7499000)
        librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xb7490000)
        libpgicu23.so => not found
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xb748b000)
        libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3 => not found
        libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xb745e000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xb72bc000)
        /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb77c3000)
```

*UPDATE*

I copied "libpgicu23.so" to /usr/lib and it solved that problem, but I still need "libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3", but when I grabbed one from the internet it said "error while loading shared libraries: /usr/lib/libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3: ELF file OS ABI invalid"

I actually even made a symlink from "libstdc++-libc6.2-2.so.3" to "libstdc++.so", but even though it solved the problem via ldd, it caused this error when I queried isql..

> isql: symbol lookup error: /usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1023.so: undefined
>   symbol: __builtin_vec_new

I've never installed odbc on a *nix box, but we did the same thing on a windows box and it worked fine.  Any input appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Check unixODBC and your driver are the same architecture i.e., run:

```
which isql
file xxx (whatever came back from above)
file /usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1023.so
```

They should both be 32 bit or 64 bit. A 64 bit unixODBC cannot use 32 bit drivers and vice versa.

You should not need that symlink.

Run ldd on /usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1023.so to ensure all dependencies are found.

Check /usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1023.so is executable.

BTW, I presume you got your labels the wrong way around as your odbc.ini file contents should be the odbcinst.ini and vice versa.

Comment: Okay I made an edit to my question with more info.

It's freaky because I actually did have the ini files in reverse, however when I reverse them, the error becomes worse (says it cannot find DSN/Driver).  However when I run ldd, I get some missing dependencies, so I'm going to try to fix that, I found something that I think might help here: http://remidian.com/progress/progress-openedge-database-101b-install-on-centos-rhel.html

Comment: Ordinarily it would not make any sense that you had the ini files the wrong way around but as unixODBC allows you to specify either driver = XXX where XXX is an entry in odbcint.ini OR Driver=path_to_shared_object you got away with it. The fact that everything is 32 bit os good however, you re your missing dependency, you cannot do what you did and expect it to work. The ABI invalid suggests you've installed an incompatible shared object. It is not as simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

One thing to check is the minor version numbers of the unixODBC libs that the driver is linked against. Since unixODBC 2.3.1 I changed the minor lib number to 2 to reflect the change in the SQLLEN size on 64 bit platforms. However if the driver lib was linked against a earlier version it will be looking for a libodbc.so.1, and current sources provide libodbc.so.2. Simple solution is to provide a sym link from the *.so.1 to the *.so.2. The same is also true of libodbcinst.so, so check that as well.