# ODBC lib Specified driver could not be loaded

Tags: linux, odbc, drivers, openedge, progress-db

I am trying to install ODBC drivers and I am running into brick walls.

```
[root@Crux pkg]# isql -v
[IM002][DataDirect][ODBC lib] Data source name not found and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
[root@Crux pkg]# isql -3 SUBS2A
[IM003][DataDirect][ODBC lib] Specified driver could not be loaded
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

My INI files are as follows;

## odbcinst.ini

```
[ProgressOpenEdge]
Description = ODBC for Progress OpenEdge
Driver = /usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1023.so
;Setup = /usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1023.so
FileUsage = 1
```

## odbc.ini

```
[SUBS2A]
Driver = ProgressOpenEdge
Description = Fail
DatabaseName = SUBS
PortNumber = 4000
HostName = 192.168.1.2
LogonID = SYSPROGRESS
Password = SYSPROGRESS
APILevel = 1
ConnectFunctions = YYN
CPTimeout = 60
DriverODBCVer = 03.50
FileUsage = 0
SQLLevel = 0
UsageCount = 1
ArraySize = 50
DefaultLongDataBuffLen = 2048
DefaultIsolationLevel = REPEATABLE READ
StaticCursorLongColBuffLen = 4096
[ODBC]
InstallDir = /usr/dlc/odbc
Trace = 0
TraceFile = odbctrace.out
TraceDll = /usr/dlc/odbc/lib/odbctrac.so
UseCursorLib = 0
```

I have already made sure all dependencies are loaded properly via ldd.

**UPDATE**

OUTPUT OF: strace isql -v
http://pastebin.com/tXFY4vVt

OUTPUT OF: strace isql -3 SUBS2A
http://pastebin.com/Yu5e54mR

OUTPUT OF: /tmp/odbctrace.out
http://pastebin.com/0kgvNdWv

Thanks

Comment: Never mind.  I was suffering from a brain-cramp.

Comment: Have you tested network connectivity on the specific TCP port ? For instance with nc 192.168.1.2 4000

Comment: check the drivers for compatibility issues with your system's architecture and with the server.

Comment: You should have linked to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318463/unixodbc-driver-manager-cannot-open-specified-library-on-install

Comment: I didn't link to it because it is no longer relevant and the issue was resolved in another manner unrelated to the update on that post.

Comment: I really think the error message has changed but the internal cause is still the same: all required libraries are not properly loaded...

Comment: This question was never actually solved, but I figured I'd award the answer anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check that your ODBC driver is loadable:

```
ldd /usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1023.so
```

Probably the loader fails to find dependencies as *shared objects* (*so* libraries) that are not available yet in your environment or available in different version.

I recommend you add `/usr/dlc/odbc/lib/` or maybe other paths according to your system:

- either in the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- either add a specific file for linux loader, for instance `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/odbc-pgoe.conf` with the line `/usr/dlc/odbc/lib/` and refresh with `ldconfig` (best option)

Please report the `ldd` command output if problem persists. Maybe expected libraries file names do not match exactly your Linux distribution.

**Update :**
The [last comment of this post](http://www.virtadept.com/?p=200) confirms that a ld.so.conf file is a solution to get the driver working. You should test it.

This forum refers to a [similar situation](http://www.progresstalk.com/showthread.php?118760-OpenEdge-10-2B-and-ODBC-Linux-connection). Maybe the solution will fix your issue.

If still wrong, please report the output of `strace isql -3 SUBS2A`. You will probably get a clue there of what is wrong like a failed library loading, a file access permission issue or whatever, just before the error message is written.

Comment: Yeah that's been done already, everything loads... apologies, I'll edit my question.

Comment: Have you used the /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ method I propose or the "move" described in your previous question ? You should not move libraries from one location to an other... Libraries may be loaded dynamically by the C code itself (without references for loader in ELF). So I recommend you test all libraries from your ODBC driver installation (probably all in /usr/dlc/odbc/lib) with "ldd".

Comment: strace isql -v: http://pastebin.com/tXFY4vVt

Also, in /etc/ld.so.conf.d/ all I see is perl.conf, but I don't think that is supported by the system.  I did put it in the environment file(s) and ran export also.  I voted up your answer as helpful, appreciate it a lot, but still not a solution.

Comment: Here are my instructions: create a file "/etc/ld.so.conf.d/odbc-pgoe.conf" with a single line as content: "/usr/dlc/odbc/lib/". It is confirmed by http://www.virtadept.com/?p=200 It should work really

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake about the command to monitor. The "isql -v" error message is expected, probably you have not set a default driver. Please send output of "strace isql -3 SUBS2A" and the content of /tmp/odbctrace.out

Comment: Sorry, here is the new version:
strace: http://pastebin.com/Yu5e54mR
odbctrace.out: http://pastebin.com/0kgvNdWv

Comment: The only thing I find strange is ";mystest is" that is read from /etc/odbc.ini Maybe there is an syntax error in your file somewhere.

Comment: ugh I forgot I replaced those files with another attempt at a different configuration, I'll have to get back to this later...

Answer (score 0):

(1) You can check whether the driver is correct before using it.

```
$ ivtestlib /usr/dlc/odbc/lib/pgoe1023.so
```

(2) Watching the log when loading drivers
In a console,

```
tail -f /path/to/SysLog_OrOtherName.file
```

In another console,

```
odbc.sh
```

Comment: My system doesn't have that utility and I have no idea about the syslog you're talking about.